# how do I convert AND to NAND using logic?

Tags: logic

I could convert OR to NAND, but I am stuck on AND. I can convert AND to interms of XOR, but still find no way to convert it to NAND

Comment: You need some form of inversion...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to negate the output of A NAND B, and you can negate something just by NANDing it to itself, so A AND B = (A NAND B) NAND (A NAND B).